# $p$-adic field with infinite residue field.

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I am reading J M Fontaine's [book](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~yiouyang/galoisrep.pdf) where on page 7 the following definition is made:

> A ***local field***($K$) is a complete discrete valuation field whose reside field($k$) is a perfect field of characteristic $p > 0$.
>   A ***$p$-adic field*** is a local field of characteristic $0$.

Immediately afterwards he makes the remark that finite extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$ are the only $p$-adic fields with finite residue field. So I tried to find an example of a $p$-adic field $K$ which has infinite residue field.

$K$ has to be of zero characteristic, so it contains $\mathbb Q$. I am not sure of the next claim, and it is vague. Since $K$ is a complete field w.r.t. a norm, by Ostrowski it has to be a $\mathbb Q_p$ or $\mathbb R$ and extensions thereof. Since we want to have infinite residue field, we are left with $\mathbb R$ and its extensions. I tried $\mathbb R((x))$ and $\mathbb C((x))$ (with $x$ indeteminate, and valuation being measured by the power of $x$) since we are in search of a discrete valuation field. But they fail to produce residue fields of positive characteristic. Since local fields are necessarily non-archimedean, will considering valuation subrings of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ help? Are there any such subrings? Somebody kindly help. Thank you!!

Comment: You can find a full answer to your question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085602/discrete-non-archimedean-valued-field-with-infinite-residue-field).

Comment: Actually any field $k$ of characteristic $p$ is the residue field of a discrete valuation ring of characteristic zero, and you can even add the condition that the maximal ideal is generated by $p$, which then makes the ring uniquely determined by $k$ (it is called a Cohen ring).

Comment: In this case, it is perhaps worthwhile to follow the usual (although usually boring, but not here) Bourbaki way, from general to particular, as in Serre's reference book on "Local Fields" (LF for short). At first, discrete valuation rings A (d.v.r.) are introduced, with fields of fractions K and residual fields k, without any further hypothesis. In passing, it is shown that  : (1) K is locally compact iff K is complete and k is finite ; (2)If A is complete, A and k have the same characteristic, and k is perfect, then A is isomorphic to k[[T]] ; (3) If A is complete and A and k have unequal ...

Comment: ... characteristics, k is the residual field of  the "Witt ring" W(k), which can be viewed as "the maximal unramified subring of A". Then Serre goes on to study ramification and norm groups, for which the extension of residual fields must be assumed to be separable, the results being sharper if k is perfect.

Comment: The "arithmetic" begins with the Brauer group, for which k must be assumed perfect. When arriving to local class field theory, one usually supposes that k is finite, because of the prominent role of the Frobenius automorphism for finite fields. Hence the notion of "quasi-finite" residual fields introduced in chapter 13 , §2 of LF : k is perfect + an "axiomatization" of the Frobenius .